# Calculating Margin & Padding Height in Fluid / Responsive Layout

Tags: css, grid, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I understand how to calculate `margin-left`/`padding-left` and `margin-right`/`padding-right` in a fluid/responsive layout. But what about `margin-top`/`padding-top` and `margin-bottom`/`padding-bottom`?

For example, I have this code:

```
header h1{padding:10px 0 0 15px;}
```

When I convert this to a fluid layout get this:

```
header h1{padding:10px 0 0 8.823529411765%;}
```

How do I convert the padding-top? By diving by 16px (the body font size)? When I do that, the result is more than 10px effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the margin's and padding to respond to the size of the font it's best to use an em for your unit. While complicated due to the inheritance, an em is a typographic unit representing the vertical height of 1 line of text. For more information see Jon Tangerine's article:

http://jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css

Also, Jon has supplied a px to em conversion table:
http://jontangerine.com/silo/css/pixels-to-ems/

While it's common to use em's for things like line-height and margins, you can also use them for literally any property in place of pixels.

Comment: Apparently it isn't good to use `em` for `line-height` because it can result in uneven spacing — is this true? [One author](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-line-height/) likens `em` to `px` in this regard; and [this author also suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height) to use unitless `line-height` instead... I'm at a loss. I thought `em` was the ultimate answer.